# Is there a way to get the current spring application context while debugging without using dependency injection nor ApplicationContextAware interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-context

What i am looking for is getting the spring application context somehow along the following lines :

```
ApplicationContext ac = SomeSpringClass.getCurrentContext() 
// As you may notice, the SomeSpringClass is not real
// it's just what i am looking for as an example
```

other solution are welcome as long as the do not use the classic ways to get the application context (@Autowired, implementing ApplicationContextAware, Constructor injection, Setter injection...)-

Comment: You can use the return value of `SpringApplication.run(args);`

Comment: thanks @Unmitigated, this solution could be used whenever i need the current spring context ? or i need to get it and store it somewhere when the first time the application runs ?

Comment: You would store it on application startup. Why do you want to avoid Autowired though?

Comment: Sometimes i need to access the application context while debugging the code and i find it disappointing to have to inject it through @Autowired every time i need it when debugging

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (a bean than has a static reference to the context):

```java
@Component
public class StaticSpringApplicationContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context = null;

    private static void setContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @EventListener
    public static void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        setContext(event.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        setContext(applicationContext);
    }

}
```

and then anywhere in your code when your app is running you can:

`StaticSpringApplicationContext.getContext()`

this bean will initialize the static variable as soon as the application is loaded and this is it's only purpose :)

Comment: thanks radu-sebastian-lazin, but it's not what i'm looking for. as i discussed with @Unmitigated, i need to access it during debug time so it's somehow an overkill to create this class

Comment: Well this will work in debug mode as well, and you can just copy paste it in your project and after your debug is done just remove the `@Component` and it won't be instantiated or maybe add a `@Conditional`